# Including templates from classpath with Apache Velocity

Tags: java, spring, velocity

I'm getting a `ResourceNotFound` exception with Velocity trying to use the `#parse` directive (and getting the same thing with `#include`).  I know that my `ClassPathResourceLoader` is configured correctly, because if I remove the `#parse` directive, the templates render fine.  The template that I'm trying to include is in the same jar file as the template that's rendering correctly, so it's not a location issue, either.

I know from the Velocity docs that templates must be in `TEMPLATE_ROOT` and that you can also register both a `FileResourceLoader` and a `ClasspathResourceLoader`.  I've tried both to no avail.

I find it hard to believe that you cannot use `#include` or `#parse` with the `ClasspathResourceLoader`, but I've tried everything I can think of. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it working.  Even though the other template files being included in the `#parse` directive were in the same directory as the template containing the `#parse` directive, I needed to add the path (relative to the root of the jar file) to them.

Answer (score 4):

alternatively, you can add the following to your velocity.properties to enable Relative Paths:

```
eventhandler.include.class = org.apache.velocity.app.event.implement.IncludeRelativePath
```